# Qt deployment issue (MinGW inside)

Tags: c++, qt, dll, deployment, mingw

I try to deploy a Qt app on a basic Windows 7 Pro SP1 machine.
My app works fine when I run it inside Qt Creator or on any machine with Qt insllated.

I have read a lot of posts and try many different things without success.

Things tried :

- Windeploy Qt
- Quick and dirty method of Qt Wiki
- Add mingwm10.dll
- Add libEGL.dll
- Check loaded dll with dependency walker
- Check loaded dll with Qt Creator debugger

My app crashes when I run it with these two error messages :

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows".
>
> This application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unsual way. Please contact...

This is my current tree (obtained with windeployqt) :
*.exe

*.dll

platforms/qwindows.dll

imageformats/*.dll

iconengines/*.dll

With dependency walker, I have some red lines even if the app runs normally but nothing interesting.

Dev machine info :

- Windows 7 Pro Sp1 64 Bits
- Qt Creator 3.3.0
- MinGW 4.9.1 32 Bits
- Qt SDK 5.4.0

I'm probably doing something wrong but what ?!

The executable seems to search something in the Qt base directory because when I rename it the deployed app doesn't want to work anymore.

Need help please ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution...
I added this line at the very beginning of my main function :

```
QApplication::addLibraryPath("./");
```

After that, windeployqt does the job.
I hope it will help someone in the future.